# Parameters for training a sentence-similarity model using Bert?

Tags: nlp, bert, finetuning, semantic-similarity

I have a list of sentences :

```
sentences = ["Missing Plate", "Plate not found"]
```

I am trying to find the most similar sentences in the list by using Transformers model with [Huggingface embedding](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/paraphrase-MiniLM-L6-v2). I am able to find the similar sentences but the model is still not able to identify the difference between :

```
"Message ID exists"  
"Message ID doesn't exist"
```

[Note: I am trying to find the similarity by using the [Cosine similarity](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/util.html#sentence_transformers.util.cos_sim) from pytorch]

Can you suggest me ways to hyperparameter tune my model so that the model can weigh in more on the negative words and consider them opposite?

I found the [list of parameters that can be tuned](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.20.1/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments) but not sure what the best parameters would be

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't know Huggingface but it might not be possible. Generally negation (also irony, hedging, etc) is difficult to handle: at the end of the day the model doesn't understand anything, it only tries to imitate what it's been fed as training data.

Comment: Thanks, @Erwan!